# Selenium slow to start driver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Take the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.quit()
```

This code takes around 5 seconds to run. As I understand it, ChromeDriver is starting a new instance of Chrome each time this is run.

This is running on Ubuntu 12.04.

In my application speed is of high importance. Is there a way to make this run quicker?

Thanks

Comment: You are correct, it is starting a new instance of chrome each time.  You could look up ways to make chrome startup faster, improve computer specs, or run your code in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with MrTi above but you may want to also check your proxy settings.

I have seen slow browser starts in Windows when the proxy is set from a pac file which was either not available or looking for unavailable proxies. Whether this is true in Linux, I cannot say.

Removing proxies if not required may speed things up.

NB. When the proxies were available, the opening speed was unaffected. So it is not the use of the proxy but it's unavailability.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, any ideas how I can check the proxy settings? Chrome is running headless so I can't just go into the GUI to change it..

Comment: Proxy settings are global across Windows applications. You can use a standard Chrome instance to set them and it will get applied to all other instances